# Omniture Adobe Single Page React implementation not showing up in reporting

Tags: adobe-analytics

We have a react implementation for adobe analytics, the network calls are exactly the same from non react vs react. The same variables with the same values are being sent to both, but it seems like the react side doesn't show up correctly in Adobe Reporting, even though people are confirm the configuration is the same for all environments.

Did anybody run into any issues, and any possible solutions they took to get it to work properly. Thanks

This is a sample call removed some of the URLS where XXX is, the call returns an OK 200

```
.   AQB:1
.   ndh:1
.   pf:1
.   t:13/1/2018 19:41:45 2 300
.   ts:1518568905165
.   fid:222B73C92E72E4AF-1050B1DB767A269E
.   ce:ISO-8859-1
.   ns:XXX
.   pageName:motorsport
.   g:XXX
.   r:XXX
.   cc:USD
.   ch:motorsport
.   server:XXX
.   state:New Jersey
.   zip:07024
.   events:prodView,event39
.   products:Modules;Mod053;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod050;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod054;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod047;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod053;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod050;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod054;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod047;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod053;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod050;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod054;;;event39=1,Modules;Mod047;;;event39=1
.   c1:D=g
.   v1:D=pageName
.   v2:product research: videos
.   v3:Organic
.   c9:motorsport: touring cars: index
.   c10:motorsport
.   v23:homepage: join
.   v24:73b3d36a-2f59-41c7-aae6-73d13c08d9b8
.   v28:Mod: Navigation: MOTORSPORT: GT
.   v30:33c03cef-942b-47a9-a95a-c33bac0c21d0
.   v31:Logged
.   c32:D=v28
.   c35:D=v30
.   v35:Less than 1 day
.   v36:7:30PM
.   c37:D=v31
.   v37:Tuesday
.   v38:Weekday
.   c39:28
.   c40:D=v36
.   c41:D=v37
.   c42:D=v38
.   v42:D=ch
.   v43:D=g
.   v44:D=s_vi
.   v45:c30e9d2d-d35a-4297-8892-efcae2d76dcc
.   c46:D=v35
.   c49:0f124b6a-a68a-49fd-95ec-047f440be29f
.   c50:2.0.0 | 11.27.2017
.   c52:D=v24
.   c60:D=v60
.   v60:XXX
.   v61:Active
.   c68:D=v68
.   v68:MTOD: 2c92c0f952f30dd50152f64979211f69
.   c74:D=v74
.   v74:2c92c0f860017d940160043310752610
.   s:1440x900
.   c:24
.   j:1.6
.   v:N
.   k:Y
.   bw:1314
.   bh:761
.   AQE:1
```

The behavior shows up in the adobe debugger and network calls fine, just never populates in the reports, or if it does there are a lot of unspecified instead of actual values, majority of the times it's doesn't show up at all.

The main question is if the network calls are the same is this a code issue or config issue? Thanks

Comment: Adobe Analytics doesn't care or have any knowledge about your site being react vs. non-react. Look closer at the network requests sent to Adobe. Provide examples of both, if you want us to help.

Comment: Also, be more clear about what you mean by "doesn't show up correctly." As in, a certain report is not populating with proper values? Not at all? Or no data sent at all not even basic hit data?

Comment: @CrayonViolent thanks for the response, it's hard to narrow down, some variable show up maybe like 5%, but it seems like everything is iffy even basic hits, other variables don't show up at all like a custom SessionID(cookies), it's a big mess where reporting data isn't populating at all. So we are trying to figure out if it's a configuration error or code error. The variables have correct behavior on the front-end, they show up in the adobe debugger and network calls, would this rule out code issues?

Comment: Might of found the issue notice that we are sending timestamp ts: this variable isn't on the other calls, will update if resolved.